# Labels in QGIS 3.22.4 are not showing up for two polygons

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am delineating forest stand types and need each stand labeled. Stands 2 through 7 show labels, but for some reason unbeknownst to me, stands 1 and 8 are not showing. I have Googled the heck out of it and tried everything I saw (messing around with 'show label' type functions) and no luck. Zooming in and out does nothing either.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the field attributes?
If one of the fields is null for either 1 or 8, string concatenation with '||' will break; in that case concatenate function would be required.

Comment: @Cushen You are right! There are nulls in both! How do I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment some of the fields are *null*.
In order to deal with this we need to use the **concat()** function:

```
 concat( "field1" , '\n' , "field2" )
```

Using the user fields, that would be:

```
 concat( "Standid" , '\n' , "TimberType", ' ', "SizeClass", '',"Density", '\n' , "AltTT", ' ', "AltSS", '', "AltDensity", '\n', "Acerage", ' Ac. ' )
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: I added a snip of my expression dialog. Where would I put the concat function in here?

Comment: as shown in the example but concat( at the start, replace || with , and then put ) at the end